# tabset with ng-repeat usage to build dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use angular ui tab (angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and expect with ng-repeat I can make it dynamic, means user can add tab. But unexpected it repeat twice.

here is the demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/iHi1aOfbzsVd1vdX3Tg8?p=preview

the tab work fine with this

```
  <tabset vertical="true" >
    <tab heading="{{tab.name}}"><div ng-view></div></tab>
    <tab heading="{{tab.name}}"><div ng-view></div></tab>
  </tabset>
```

but I added ng-repeat="tab in tabs" to tabset tag and expecting later can push new tab into it. but it failed, it duplicated the entire tab.

Answer (score 1):

remove your `<div ng-view>`, put ng-view into `<div class="mainWrap" ng-view>`

http://plnkr.co/edit/TfnXp0GOzx904jMsO5RT?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="daysofme">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainControl">

<div class="mainWrap" ng-view>
  <tabset vertical="true" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <tab heading="{{tab.name}}"></tab>
    <tab heading="{{tab.name}}"></tab>
  </tabset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: then the tab is gone.

Comment: didn't you need to click add?

Comment: that's the content of the tab. I've no problem for that to work. I want to add tab feature for them. Each tab should have their own tab content and tab is dynamic, means I can add tab 3, 4, 5 and so forth..

Comment: Without [ng-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can only put one ng-view.